# View server response string and all hidden newline characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm dealing with an LMS (Learning Management System) in which I have NO access to the server-side code. All I can view is the response the server gives me. It returns a response in a string with newline characters, but I would like to see the string in it's raw form... showing all hidden characters. I'm not sure if this can be done, but if someone knows a way that would be great.

```
$.get(_url,{command:"GetParam",version:"2.2",session_id:_sid},function(response)
{
    console.log(response);
});
```

The code above gives me this response:

```
ERROR=0
ERROR_TEXT=Successful
VERSION=2.2
AICC_DATA=[CORE]
STUDENT_ID=0123456
STUDENT_NAME=Doe, JohnR
SCORE=
TIME=00:00:00
CREDIT=C
LESSON_LOCATION=1_5
LESSON_STATUS=NULL
[Core_Lesson]
[Objectives_Status]
```

Comment: Check out Fiddler or Wireshark.

Comment: Why the negative down vote?

Comment: what do you mean by "raw form"? that *is* the output from the server, coinciding with what you'd see by a viewsource by going directly to the url in your browser. Do mean to say you want to be able to see the returned headers and stuff?  As Brad mentioned, you can use a sniffer like fiddler or wireshark. Alternatively there are lots of browser addons (and native development tools) that will show it. Eg. IE and Chrome both have built-in dev tools to see requests and responses made For FF you can use firebug or httpfox or similar

Comment: p.s. i didn't -1 but perhaps it was because you aren't entirely clear on what you actually want or are wanting to do? what's your actual goal here?

Comment: I've never used Fiddler, but I'm playing with it now. In it's "raw" form I mean viewing the string in a way that will show all characters. Currently, when I view the string the newline characters do not show up. The string has implemented the newline characters.

Comment: @CrayonViolent The question is very clear.